# XC16 compiler local variable assignment doesn't work

Tags: c, stack, pic, microchip, xc16

I'm using PIC30F4011 with compiler XC16. I noticed that the assignment of local variable doesn't work, but if I declare the variables to be global it works.

In the following function, after the assignment statement: `addr = b_flashStart;`, the `addr` is supposed to be `0x1600`, but it is `0` instead.

```
uint16_t __attribute__((section("boot"))) b_calcCrc(void)
{
    uint16_t addrU = 0;
    uint16_t crcFlash;
    uint16_t index = 0;
    uint16_t addr = 0;
    
    addrU = 0x0000;
    addr = b_flashStart;
    crcFlash  = 0xFFFF;
    for(addr = b_flashStart; addr < 0x7fc0/*b_flashEnd*/; addr += 0x0040)
    {
        b_flashRowRead( addrU, addr, flashReadBuffer );  // Row of 32 pairs
        for(index = 0; index < 0x40;)
        {
            b_temp = flashReadBuffer[index++];
            crcFlash = b_crc16( crcFlash, b_temp );
            b_temp = flashReadBuffer[index++];
            crcFlash = b_crc16( crcFlash, b_temp );
            b_temp = flashReadBuffer[index++];
            crcFlash = b_crc16( crcFlash, b_temp );
            b_temp = flashReadBuffer[index++];
            crcFlash = b_crc16( crcFlash, b_temp );
        }
    }

    return crcFlash;
}
```

Here is the whole file:

```
/******************************************************************************/
/* Files to Include                                                           */
/******************************************************************************/

/* Device header file */
#include <xc.h>

#include <stdint.h>        // Includes uint16_t definition
#include <stdbool.h>       // Includes true/false definition  
#define  FCY    20000000UL
#include <libpic30.h>

/******************************************************************************/
//  Programming format  Memory Map
//  -----------------
//  |    0x0000     |
//  |    0x0002     |   Boot vector
//  |    0x0004     |   Unlock & write vector
//  |               |   
//  |               |
//  |  Boot Block   |   (this program)
//  |               |
//  |    0x1000     |   Re-mapped Reset Vector
//  |    0x0600     |   Re-mapped Interrupt Vector table
//  |               |
//  |       |       |
//  |               |
//  |    0X1000     |   User program space
//  |               |
//  |       |       |
//  |               |
//  |    0xFFFE     |
//  -----------------
//


/*****************************************************************************/
#define MINOR_VERSION   0x00        // Version
#define MAJOR_VERSION   0x01

#define RC_DLE      0x01
#define RC_STX      0x02

#define STX     0x023       // use # instead
#define ETX     0x04
#define DLE     0x05

/*****************************************************************************/
#define CHKSUM      0x00        // Checksum accumulator
#define COUNTER     0x01        // General counter
#define ABTIME_H    0x02
#define ABTIME_L    0x03
#define RXDATA      0x04
#define TXDATA      0x05

#define COMMAND     0x02        // Data mapped in receive buffer
#define DATA_COUNT  0x03    
#define ADDRESS_L   0x04
#define ADDRESS_H   0x05
#define ADDRESS_UL  0x06
#define ADDRESS_UH  0x07
/*****************************************************************************/
/******************************************************************************/
/* Main Program                                                               */
/******************************************************************************/
#define pinBoot         PORTBbits.RB3       // Programming flag
//#define pinStby         PORTBbits.RB1       // CAN standby
#define bootFlag 1
#define baudConstant 129        // 9600 baud with PLL_8

bool b_processRecord(uint16_t);
uint16_t b_getRecord(void);
void b_writeUART(char ch);
char b_readUART(void);
void b_initUART(void);        // Initialize UART 2 to 115200 baud
void b_initCAN(void);         // for debugging output - watch on CANAlyzer 
void b_sendCAN(void);
void b_bootend();             // jump to application
uint16_t b_crc16(uint16_t crc, uint16_t data);
void b_crcMessage(bool flash, bool eeProm);
uint16_t b_calcCrc(void);
//unsigned int b_eeprom_read_int(unsigned int address);
//unsigned int b_eeprom_write_int(unsigned int address, unsigned int data);

#define b_flashStart  0x1600
#define b_flashEnd    0x7FFF
#define b_eepromStart 0xFC00
#define b_eepromEnd   0xFFFF
#define b_poly        0x8408    // crc16 polynoimial

union CAN
{
    uint8_t  bytes[256];
    uint16_t words[128];
}b_CAN;

union Buffer
{
    uint8_t  charBuffer[256];
    uint16_t wordBuffer[128];
}b;

uint16_t b_receivePointer;
unsigned char b_checksum;
unsigned char b_bufferCANb[8];
unsigned char b_bufferCANw[4];
uint16_t i;
uint16_t testSID;
bool booting = false;
uint16_t b_temp;
static uint16_t flashReadBuffer[256];
//uint16_t b_eepromRead(uint16_t adr);
//void b_eepromWrite(uint16_t adr, uint16_t data);
static uint16_t crc16_calc = 0;
static uint16_t crc16_sv = 0;
void __attribute__((section("boot"))) b_boot(void)
{
    uint16_t bufSize;
 //   uint16_t crc16_calc;
 //   uint16_t crc16_sv;
    ADPCFGbits.PCFG3 = 1;       // RB3 set to digital input
    TRISBbits.TRISB3 = 1;       // Input  - Boot Flag
    TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 0;    //LED
//    TRISBbits.TRISB1 = 0;       // Output - CAN standby
//    pinStby          = 0;       // make transceiver active
    
 //   crc16_sv = b_eeprom_read_int(EEPROM_APP_CRC_ADDR);
    crc16_calc = b_calcCrc();

    PORTDbits.RD0 = 1;
    booting = true;
    b_initUART();               // initialize the UART
    b_initCAN();
    testSID = 0x030;            // signal we are in boot mode
    b_sendCAN();
    
    b_flashRowRead( 0, 0x7fc0, flashReadBuffer ); 
    crc16_sv = flashReadBuffer[0x3e];

    if((pinBoot != bootFlag) && (crc16_sv == crc16_calc))   // if no boot flag - go to user code
        b_bootend();

    while(booting)
    {
        bufSize = b_getRecord();
        if(pinBoot != bootFlag) b_bootend();
        b_processRecord(bufSize);
    }
    b_bootend();
}

 uint16_t checkFlashCrc;
bool __attribute__((section("boot"))) b_processRecord(uint16_t bufSize)
{
 //   uint16_t flashReadBuffer[256];
    uint16_t crcFlash;
    uint16_t crcEeprom;
    uint16_t index;
    uint16_t checkFlashCrc;
    uint16_t checkEepromCrc;
    bool flashFlag = false;
    bool eePromFlag = false;

    unsigned char command = b.charBuffer[COMMAND];
    uint16_t addrU =  ((uint16_t)b.charBuffer[ADDRESS_UH] << 8) & 0xFF00 |
                 (uint16_t)b.charBuffer[ADDRESS_UL] & 0x00FF;
    uint16_t addr  = ((uint16_t)b.charBuffer[ADDRESS_H] << 8) & 0xFF00 |
                 (uint16_t)b.charBuffer[ADDRESS_L] & 0x00FF;
 
    addr  = (addr / 2) | ((addrU << 15) & 0x8000);    // make it a word address
    addrU = addrU / 2;
    
    switch(command)
    {   
        case 0x01:      // compute crc
            PORTDbits.RD0 = 1;
            testSID = 0x31;
            b_sendCAN();
            checkFlashCrc = b.wordBuffer[2];
            checkEepromCrc = b.wordBuffer[3];
           // compute eeprom checksum
            addrU = 0x007F;
            addr = 0xFC00;
            crcEeprom = 0xFFFF;
            index = b_eepromEnd - b_eepromStart + 1;
            for(addr = b_eepromStart; index > 0; index -= 2, addr += 2 )  // skip upper bytes
            {
                b_temp = b_eePromRead(addrU, addr);
                crcEeprom = b_crc16(crcEeprom, b_temp);
            }
            b_flashRowRead( 0, 0x7fc0, flashReadBuffer ); 
            flashReadBuffer[0x3E] = checkFlashCrc;
            b_flashRowWrite(0, 0x7FC0, flashReadBuffer);
            b_CAN.bytes[2] = 0xFF;
            b_CAN.bytes[3] = 0xFF;
            crcFlash = b_calcCrc();
            
            if( crcFlash == checkFlashCrc ) // set check flags
            {
  //              b_eeprom_write_int(EEPROM_APP_CRC_ADDR, crcFlash);
                flashFlag = true;
                b_CAN.bytes[2] = 0x01;
                PORTDbits.RD0 = 0;
            }
            if( crcEeprom == checkEepromCrc )
            {
                eePromFlag = true;
                b_CAN.bytes[3] = 0x01;
            }
            b_crcMessage( flashFlag, eePromFlag );
            
            b_CAN.words[2] = crcFlash;
            b_CAN.words[3] = crcEeprom;
            testSID = 0x0032;
            b_sendCAN();
            booting = false;        // we are done
            break;
        case 0x02:      // write flash
            PORTDbits.RD0 = 0;
            if( addr >= 0x1600)
            {
                b_flashRowWrite(addrU, addr, &b.wordBuffer[4]);
            }
            break;
        case 0x03:      // erase flash
            PORTDbits.RD0 = 1;
            if( addr >= 0x1600)
            {
                b_flashRowErase(addrU, addr);
            }
            break;
        case 0x04:      // erase eeprom
            b_eePromAllErase(0x007F, 0xFC00);
            break;
        case 0x05:      // write eeprom
            if( addrU == 0x007F)
            {
                b_eePromRowWrite(addrU, addr, &b.wordBuffer[4]);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return true;
} 

uint16_t __attribute__((section("boot"))) b_calcCrc(void)
{
    uint16_t addrU = 0;
    uint16_t crcFlash;
    uint16_t index = 0;
    uint16_t addr = 0;
    
    addrU = 0x0000;
    addr = b_flashStart;
    crcFlash  = 0xFFFF;
    for(addr = b_flashStart; addr < 0x7fc0/*b_flashEnd*/; addr += 0x0040)
    {
        b_flashRowRead( addrU, addr, flashReadBuffer );  // Row of 32 pairs
        for(index = 0; index < 0x40;)
        {
            b_temp = flashReadBuffer[index++];
            crcFlash = b_crc16( crcFlash, b_temp );
            b_temp = flashReadBuffer[index++];
            crcFlash = b_crc16( crcFlash, b_temp );
            b_temp = flashReadBuffer[index++];
            crcFlash = b_crc16( crcFlash, b_temp );
            b_temp = flashReadBuffer[index++];
            crcFlash = b_crc16( crcFlash, b_temp );
        }
    }
#if 0
    b_flashRowRead( addrU, addr, flashReadBuffer );  // Row of 32 pairs
    for(index = 0; index < 0x3D;)
    {
        b_temp = flashReadBuffer[index++];
        crcFlash = b_crc16( crcFlash, b_temp );
        b_temp = flashReadBuffer[index++];
        crcFlash = b_crc16( crcFlash, b_temp );
    }
#endif
    return crcFlash;
}
//#endif
uint16_t __attribute__((section("boot"))) b_getRecord()
{
    // find two consecutive STX characters
    char currentChar = ETX;
    char previousChar = STX;

    while((currentChar != STX) || (previousChar != STX) )
    {
        previousChar = currentChar;
        currentChar = b_readUART();
    }
    b_CAN.bytes[0] = previousChar;
    b_CAN.bytes[1] = currentChar;
    b_receivePointer = 2;
    while( b_receivePointer < 8 )
    {
        currentChar  = b_readUART();
        b.charBuffer[b_receivePointer++] = currentChar;
    }
    b_CAN.words[1] = b.wordBuffer[1];
    b_CAN.words[2] = b.wordBuffer[2];
    b_CAN.words[3] = b.wordBuffer[3];
    b_CAN.words[4] = b.wordBuffer[4];
   
    uint16_t length =  b.charBuffer[b_receivePointer - 5]; // data length
    for( i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        currentChar  = b_readUART();
        b.charBuffer[b_receivePointer++] = currentChar;
       
    }
    return b_receivePointer; 
}

void __attribute__((section("boot"))) b_crcMessage(bool flash, bool eeProm)
{
    if(flash)
    {
        b_writeUART('A');
        b_writeUART('C');
        b_writeUART('K');       
    }
    else
    {
        b_writeUART('N');
        b_writeUART('A');
        b_writeUART('K');       
    }
    b_writeUART(',');
    if(eeProm)
    {
        b_writeUART('A');
        b_writeUART('C');
        b_writeUART('K');       
    }
    else
    {
        b_writeUART('N');
        b_writeUART('A');
        b_writeUART('K');       
    }
    b_writeUART('\r');
    b_writeUART('\n');
}

void __attribute__((section("boot"))) b_writeUART(char ch)
{
    while(U2STAbits.TRMT == 0);         // Wait for transmit register empty
    U2TXREG = ch;                       // send character
}

char __attribute__((section("boot"))) b_readUART()
{
    while(U2STAbits.URXDA == 0); //&&         // Wait for receive register not empty
            //(pinBoot == bootFlag) );        // abort if boot flag is reset
    if(pinBoot != bootFlag) b_bootend();
    char chr = U2RXREG;
    return chr;
}

void __attribute__((section("boot"))) b_initUART(void)
{
    U2MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;              // Enable UART pins
    U2BRG             = baudConstant;   // 9600 0r 115200 Baud - w/PLL_8
    U2MODEbits.PDSEL  = 0;              // 8 bit, no parity
    U2MODEbits.STSEL  = 0;              // 1 stop bit
    U2STAbits.UTXISEL = 0;              // Interrupt when char transferred to Transmit Shift register
    U2STAbits.UTXEN   = 1;              // Enable transmitter
    U2STAbits.URXISEL = 1;              // Interrupt for each char received
    IEC1bits.U2RXIE   = 0;              // Disable receive interrupts
    IEC1bits.U2TXIE   = 0;              // Disable transmit interrupts
}

void __attribute__((section("boot"))) b_sendCAN() // for testing output
{
//    while(C1TX2CONbits.TXREQ != 0);   // overwrite if not send yet
    C1TX2CONbits.TXREQ = 0;             // only used for diagnostic messages
    C1TX2B1 = b_CAN.words[0];
    C1TX2B2 = b_CAN.words[1];
    C1TX2B3 = b_CAN.words[2];
    C1TX2B4 = b_CAN.words[3];
    C1TX2SIDbits.SID10_6 = (testSID >> 6) & 0x001F;
    C1TX2SIDbits.SID5_0  =  testSID & 0x003F;
    C1TX2DLCbits.DLC   = 8;
    C1TX2SIDbits.SRR = 0;           // Normal message
    C1TX2CONbits.TXPRI = 0;             // Lowest transmission priority
    C1TX2SIDbits.TXIDE = 0;             // Standard Identifier
    C1TX2CONbits.TXREQ = 1;             // Transmit the message
    return;
}

void __attribute__((section("boot"))) b_initCAN(void) // for testing output
{
    C1CTRLbits.CANCAP    = 0;           // Disable CAN Capture
    C1CTRLbits.CANSIDL   = 1;           // Stop CAN in Idle mode
    C1CTRLbits.ABAT      = 1;           // Abort any transmit operations
    C1CTRLbits.CANCKS    = 0;           // CAN clock is 4 Fcy
    C1CTRLbits.REQOP     = 4;           // Set configuration mode
    while(C1CTRLbits.OPMODE != 4);      // wait for Configuration mode

    C1CFG1bits.SJW       = 0;           // Synchronized jump width 1 x Tq
    
    C1CFG1bits.BRP       = 0x03;        // Baud rate pre-scaler - PLL_8
    C1CFG2bits.WAKFIL    = 0;           // Filter not used for wakeup
    C1CFG2bits.SEG2PH    = 2;           // SEG2 - 3
    C1CFG2bits.SEG2PHTS  = 1;           // Freely programmable
    C1CFG2bits.SAM       = 1;           // Sample 3 times
    C1CFG2bits.SEG1PH    = 3;           // SEG1 1 - 4
    C1CFG2bits.PRSEG     = 1;           // PROP 5

    C1CTRLbits.REQOP     = 0;           // Change to normal mode
    while(C1CTRLbits.OPMODE != 0);      // wait for Normal mode
    C1INTEbits.RX0IE     = 0;           // Disable RX 0 Interrupt
    C1INTEbits.RX1IE     = 0;           // Disable RX 1 Interrupt
    C1INTEbits.TX0IE     = 0;           // Disable TX 0 Interrupt
    C1INTEbits.TX1IE     = 0;           // Disable TX 1 Interrupt
    C1INTEbits.TX2IE     = 0;           // Disable TX 2 Interrupt
    IPC6bits.C1IP        = 3;           // CAN Interrupt priority
    IEC1bits.C1IE        = 0;           // Disable CAN Interrupts
    
    C1CTRLbits.ABAT      = 1;           // Abort any transmit operations
    
    // zero CAN buffer
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        b_bufferCANb[i]   = 0x00;
        b_bufferCANb[i*2] = 0x00;
        b_bufferCANw[i]   = 0x0000;
    }
}

uint16_t __attribute__((section("boot"))) b_crc16(uint16_t crc, uint16_t data)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++, data >>= 1)
    {
        if((( crc & 0x0001 ) ^ ( data & 0x0001 )) == 0x0001 )
        {
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ b_poly;
        }
        else
        {
            crc = crc >> 1;
        }
    }
    return crc;
}


void __attribute__((section("boot"))) b_bootend(void)
{
    asm ("goto __resetPRI");
}
```

Comment: Which `addr = b_flashStart`?  The first one?  Or the one in the "for" statement?  Given that the second one overwrites the first, I'd expect optimization to discard the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You assign a value to `addr` twice and dont't use the variable between the two assignments, so the compiler will optimize the first assignment away:

First assignment:

```
addr = b_flashStart;
```

Second assignment;

```
for(addr = b_flashStart; addr < 0x7fc0/*b_flashEnd*/; addr += 0x0040)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out this redundant statement. This doesn't cause the assignment problem. It must be stack frame related. Do we need to initialize the stack frame pointer? Thanks.

Comment: No, you don't need to initialize the stack pointer, it's the job of the compiler. I guess `addr`is still `0x00`because the assignment is optimized away. Maybe have a look at the assembler listing,

Comment: Assembly looks OK